# How do I fix error: RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

The problem is that if I pass this function (in my REPL) with 08 or 09, it will give me an error.

I've tried removing parenthesizes around to see if the error would go away.

```
(defn format-pump-number [number]
  (if (.contains (str number) "0")
    (str number)
    (str "0" number))
    (if (> number 9)
      (if (< number 100)
        (str number)
        (throw (Exception. "Dispenser number can only be 2 characters!"))))
      (str "0" number))
```

I expect [number] to be returned 08 or 09 when passed that exact number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers usually interpret a number like `08` or `09` to be octal, which is an error since octal digits only go from 0..7.  Historically, it was thought that using a leading zero character `0` was a clever type of code, since the character `0` looks like the character `O` from the word `Octal`.
So, when the compiler sees an integer starting with a `0`, it is interpreted to mean "The digits coming next should be interpreted in base-8, not base-10".  Example:

```
 12  =>  twelve (parsed using base-ten)
012  =>  ten    (parsed using base-eight)
```

This attempt to be overly clever causes problems through today, as you have discovered.

So, it is not your function at all, just a bad error message.  Observe:

```
(println "val=" 8) => `val= 8`
```

but

```
(println "val=" 08)
  => Error refreshing environment: Syntax error reading source at (tst/demo/core.clj:19:20).
```

I do not get an error message regarding "Unmatched delimiter", so I'm not sure how that arose.

Comment: You cannot enter an integer literal as `08`.  Just use `8` for the number `eight`. Or, you could change the function to accept a string arg instead of an integer.  Then you can type `"8"` or `"08"`.  A string has no restrictions.